# Nginx get first part of URL

Tags: regex, nginx, url, server

In this context I'd like to get only "user1", "user2" parts of the URLs.

```sh
site.com/user1/
site.com/user2/
site.com/user2/about
site.com/user2/contact
```

When I try something like this, it gets all the URL.

```
location ~* ^/(.*)$ {
  add_header X-username $1
  # configuration
}
```

So how can I change the regex to get only first part of the URL?

Comment: Try: `^/([^/]+)/`

Comment: This looks like working. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
^/([^/]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Maq1Hw/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```